# Facebook :fberrorhttperror

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xcode4.3

[image]

How can I rectify this?
Basically what I did was I went to my Facebook settings and removed the app from there. Many users do this to remove access of the app.

When I come back to the app it should put me back into the usual sign up flow and go through the Facebook approval process again.

However when I did that here are the errors I see. I am no longer able to use the app because of these errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you go to settings--->privacy---->Facebook.

There you allow your app the access..

Clean your project and run it.your problem will get solved.If not feel free to ask me.

Enjoy..

Comment: i have fixed the error by using facebook error handler.Can you tell me How can i allow user to sign in using Safari browser and not using default Facebook in "Setting" in iPhone?

Comment: @SRS  k...you want user to sign in using safari..wait for just a minute..i will explain to you..

Comment: @SRS you use this code..NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.facebook.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
I think this will solve your problem..This will help you to open through safari..

Comment: Basically what I want is that if user is not allowed to sign in using Facebook Setting in iPhone then the user should be redirected to the web browser where he can login and authenticate the application.Hope you got my point.

Comment: Could you guide me in that as I am facing this issue and cant figure it out how to resolve it.

Comment: i did that as my problem was not resolved.still facing that same issue.So,I asked you the question on 4th comment.Once that is solved I would accept you answer.I am really sorry for that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28011/discussion-between-json-and-srs)

Comment: No not yet.Still facing that same issue.Now,I have started using a fresh project for Facebook login using the latest Facebook sdk3.2 .Could you tell me how to get the user emailId using Graph in scrumptious sample?Using that has solved some of my issues.Thanks if you could help me.